# Getting a TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'current') on Next.js

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next.js13

[TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'current')](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dkLnx.jpg) 
I'm getting this error upon running a nextjs project for the first time. This is the command I'm running:
npx create-next-app@latest my-test-app --typescript --tailwind --eslint

this is what my package.json looks like:

```
{
"name"; "my-test-app"
"version": "0.1.0",
"private": true,
"scripts": {
"dev": "next dev"
"build": "next build"
"start": "next start"
"lint": "next lint"
"dependencies": {
    "@types/node": "20.4.4",
    "@types/react": "18.2.15",
    "@types/react-dom": "18.2.7",
    "autoprefixer": "10.4.14",
    "eslint": "8.45.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "^13.4.12",
    "next": "^13.4.12-canary.0",
    "postcss": "8.4.27",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "tailwindcss": "3.3.3",
    "typescript": "5.1.6"
  }
}
```

I think its a me issue because others have ran this fine on their own.

Im running it on a 2021 macbook pro. Ive tried running npm i next@canary and its still giving me the same issue.

I literally haven't done anything yet and just ran it and it continuously gives me this error no matter how many nextjs projects I create.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out that it was one of my extensions in chrome. I don't know which one I just removed all my extensions and it seems to fix this issue